# "File.Exists" does not exist

Tags: c#, .net

I created this class "XML_Toolbox" that could be used by any of my forms to perform any of the key XML actions that i am going to be using repeatedly.  So with that being said, here is that class' code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Personal_Finance_Manager
{
    class XML_toolbox
    {
        public static void createFile (string filename, string filePath)
        {
            string createPath = filePath + @"\" + filename + ".txt";

            if (file.exists(createPath))
            {
                StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(createPath, true);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This file already exists!!! Please choose another name!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

all the individual parts were working when called from another form up until i added the:

```
if (file.exists(createPath)) {}
```

IF statement.

Now i am getting the

> The name "file" does not exist in the current context

error.  I have the

> using System.IO;

what else am i missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class name is `File` not `file`, method name is `Exists`. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: ninja'ed by 29 seconds.

Comment: Well that would do it, i guess i got lazy working in other environments and languages where it would auto capitalize names for you!

Comment: @BenW301: it can't auto-capitalize because C# is case-sensitive. `File` and `file` are two different things, so how would it know what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

It's called `File`, not `file`.

```
File.Exists()
```